# Render an iOS UIWebView to an OpenGL texture in real time

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, uiwebview

I'm currently trying to render the content of a `UIWebView` into an OpenGL texture in real time for an application. Searching on the web, I found a way to do what I wanted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118778/render-contents-of-uiview-as-an-opengl-texture) using the `renderInContext` method of the web view's layer, but it's really slow.

So I have some questions to ask you:

- I've noticed that even calling `renderInContext` method, the web view is rendered on the screen. Is there a way to *replace* the rendering method saying to the web view that we want to render into a texture **instead** of the screen? (like on Android)
- Is there a way to know if the web view has been updated (some JavaScript code has modified the page for example) to call the `renderInContext` only in this case? I didn't find anything about that into [the official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview?changes=latest_minor&language=objc).
- I saw that we can allocate specific OpenGL ES texture (**[CVOpenGLESTexture](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/cvopenglestexture?language=objc)**) with the [Core Video framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo?language=objc), is it suitable to web view rendering? Can I use that to improve the performances?

Thanks a lot for your answers.

Comment: any luck for your question ?

Comment: No, sorry, I didn't find a proper solution to this problem unfortunatly...

Comment: How can you come up with the solution for this?

Comment: Currently what I've done is call WebView's `setHidden` method to hide it before to call `renderInContext` and show it again just after. But I didn't do anything for the performance issue.